# No abre el navegador, Selenium con Python (POM)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

apenas estoy aprendiendo a hacer pruebas con selenium y python, recientemente me pidieron hacerlo usando la metodología POM así que usé esta web como base para el código https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/page-object-model-in-selenium-python/(ejemplo 1) pero en mi código ni siquiera puedo hacer que se abra el navegador, ya revisé y comparé ambos códigos y no logro encontrar la diferencia, les agradecería mucho si lo pudieran revisar tambien e indicarme cuál es el error,les dejó aquí mi código.
Este es el setup del driver, este lo copié de otro ejemplo donde si abría el navegador.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from time import sleep


class WebDriverSetup(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Driver 
chrome\chromedriver.exe")
 
    def tearDown(self):
        if (self.driver != None):
            print("Cleanup of test environment")
            self.driver.close()
            self.driver.quit()
```

Y este es el código de mi prueba, como se puede apreciar, es una prueba muy simple la que estoy intentando hacer pero ni siquiera me abre el navegador. No sé si estoy llamando mal al método o si es algo relacionado a la estructura.

```
import unittest
from time import sleep
from setUpDriver import WebDriverSetup
from login1 import Login
import time

class PruebaLogin(WebDriverSetup):

    def inicioEvou (self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("localhost:3000")
        self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)

    def buscar (self,driver):
        login = Login(driver)
        login.usuarioLog.send_keys("Liliana")
        time.sleep(2)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Deja tu código aquí en el Post para ayudarte mejor, solo coloca donde tienes el error o donde no entiendes.

Comment: Es mejor si nos das un ejemplo mínimo y reproducible. Así es más fácil para todos ayudarte.